# Can't pass integer in function C

Tags: arrays, c, function, recursion

I'm trying to create an array with dimension n in a function, i don't get why the compiler gives me this error:

> error: variable-sized object may not be initialized

> warning: excess elements in array initializer

The code is the following, the program isn't of course finished since I can't get this to work, and it gives me the same error in similar projects:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//given a number, find all binary numbers with that number of digits
int gen_num(int);
int main()
{
    int n;
    printf("Insert a number: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    gen_num(n);
    return 0;
}

int gen_num(int n){

    int num[n]={0};
    return 0;
}
```

If I try to not initialize in the declaration, but I for example try to ask the user to input some values it gives me the same error, since the array is created with dimension 0

Thanks in advance

Comment: Tip: When you get an error just paste it directly into your favourite search engine as the minimum research to do before posting a question.

Comment: Tip: Reverse the order of these definitions and you won't need the pretty much useless declaration at the top. In C code it's pretty much expected that you write your precursor functions first, then have main at or near the end.

Comment: Problem is that I'm using 2011 C so this shoudn't occur, and I've always used this notation and never had problems

Comment: C11 6.7.9/3 "The type of the entity to be initialized shall be an array of unknown size or a complete object type that is **not a variable length array type**." (emphasis mine).

Comment: What notation are you referring to? If you mean VLA (Variable Length Array), `int num[n]`, that's not the problem. The problem is the initialiser which is not allowed for VLAs.

Answer (score 0):

Use `calloc()` to allocate and initiate arrays dynamically.

```c
int gen_num(int n){
    int *num = calloc(n, sizeof(int));

    /* treat 'num' like an array of integers */
    num[3] = 3;
    
    free(num); 
    return 0;
}
```

If you only call `gen_num()` once, you don't have to call `free()`, you can let the memory leak. But call `free()` anyway, it's a good habit.

Another way is

```
int num[n];
memset(num, 0, sizeof(int) * n);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really mean to use a dynamically sized array (C99), then by definition the size of the array is not known at compile-time, thus the initializer syntax won't work. You have to explicitly initialize (using e.g. a `for`-loop or `memset()`).